# Django Migrations: run_before vs dependencies

Tags: django, migration

I always thought that dependencies made sure that all the migrations that I put there ran before the migraton I was declaring. However, today I found about run_before and Im not sure what are the differences between both. Can someon clarify the difference between run_`before` and `dependencies` when declaring a Django migration?

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0123_the_previous_migration'),
    ]

   run_before = [
    ('third_party_app', '0001_do_awesome'),
   ]
```

Answer (score 14):

`run_before` is the exact opposite of `dependencies`. You should read it as "this migration must run before these other migrations".

Generally you should be using `dependencies` over `run_before`. One use-case where you need `run_before` is if an external app has a dependency in some way on one of your migrations.

This is also explained in ["Controlling the order of migrations"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/writing-migrations/#controlling-the-order-of-migrations).

Comment: Thank you very much. "Exact opposite" was what made it clear for me. I read the link you posted before writing the question but I thought that run_before was referring to "Run this migrations before the one Im writing". Thank you!